# Why am I getting an error from texSubImage3D when loading data from an image

Tags: javascript, webgl, webgl2

I have a PNG file with dimensions 128x32128 (equivalent to 251 128x128 layers) and when I try the following:

```
gl.texStorage3D(gl.TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, 1, gl.SRGB8_ALPHA8, 128, 128, 251)
gl.texSubImage3D(gl.TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, 0, 0, 0, 0, 128, 128, 251, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, imageElement)
// imageElement.src = 128x32128.png
```

I get a browser error reading `WebGL: INVALID_VALUE: texSubImage3D: width, height or depth out of range`

However, if I try something very similar with another image of dimension 128x8192 (equivalent to 64 layers of 128x128) I get no error:

```
gl.texStorage3D(gl.TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, 1, gl.SRGB8_ALPHA8, 128, 128, 32)
gl.texSubImage3D(gl.TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, 0, 0, 0, 0, 128, 128, 32, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, imageElement)
// imageElement.src = 128x8192.png
```

*However*, if I try the same code with the original image I get the same error:

```
gl.texStorage3D(gl.TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, 1, gl.SRGB8_ALPHA8, 128, 128, 32)
gl.texSubImage3D(gl.TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, 0, 0, 0, 0, 128, 128, 32, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, imageElement)
// imageElement.src = 128x32128.png
```

This does not make any sense. Surely this is an implementation bug, as the only thing that changed from example 2 to example 3 was the image, not the parameters to texSubImage3D.

Browser: Chrome v67 on Windows 7 x64

Comment: What `gl.getParameter(gl.MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE)` returns?

Comment: Have you tried Firefox?

Comment: @Asaq Max texture size is 16,384, but I am requesting a texture that is 128x128x251...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in Chrome as it works in Firefox

```js
const ctx = document.createElement('canvas').getContext("2d");
const gl = document.createElement('canvas').getContext("webgl2");

test(1);
test(128);
test(129);

function test(slices) {
  log('slices:', slices);
  
  const height = 128 * slices;
  
  ctx.canvas.width = 128;
  ctx.canvas.height = height;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
  ctx.lineTo(128, height);
  ctx.moveTo(128, height);
  ctx.lineTo(0, 128);
  ctx.stroke();
  //document.body.appendChild(ctx.canvas);

  const tex = gl.createTexture();
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, tex);
  log("gl error:", gl.getError());
  gl.texStorage3D(gl.TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, 1, gl.RGBA8, 128, 128, slices);
  log("gl error:", gl.getError());

  gl.texSubImage3D(
     gl.TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, // GLenum target, 
     0, // GLint level, 
     0, // GLint xoffset, 
     0, // GLint yoffset, 
     0, // GLint zoffset,
     128, // GLsizei width, 
     128, // GLsizei height, 
     slices, // GLsizei depth, 
     gl.RGBA, // GLenum format, 
     gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, // GLenum type,
     ctx.canvas); // TexImageSource source

  log("gl error:", gl.getError());
  log('.');
}

function log(...args) {
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  div.textContent = [...args].join(' ');
  document.body.appendChild(div);
}
```

[Filed a bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=859400)